# Processing Azure Analysis Services with SQL Agent on Premises

Tags: sql-agent-job, sql-agent, azure-analysis-services

There is much documentation outlining how to use Azure Automation to schedule and process an Azure Analysis Services model through PowerShell script. However, there is need to trigger processing of Azure Analysis services within the steps of an on premisses SQL Agent job (SQL Server 2014).

Given Azure requires the logging in through PowerShell to trigger, how can the libraries be installed into SQL Server 2014 as well as script to successfully trigger the processing of the Azure tabular model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into the same problem using SQL Server 2012 on-prem.  To side step the issue, I setup Azure Automation jobs to refresh the cubes.  I then enabled web triggers that can easily be called from earlier versions of SQL server.